# Decision about web application architecture

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, architecture, inversion-of-control

I am facing a decision about the web application architecture I am going to work on.
We are a small team and actually I will work on it alone (everybody work on something else).

This application will consist of front-end build on the [ExtJS library](http://www.ext.net)
and it will use the model "load page, build GUI and never refresh".
On the web "desktop" there will be a lot of data windows, map views (using openlayers + GeoExt) and other stuff.
GUI should be flexible and allow every user to modify (and persist) the layout to fit his/her needs.

It should be possible to divide the application into modules / parts / ... and then let users in specific groups use only the specific modules. In other words, each group of users
can have different GUI available on the web "desktop".

Questions are:

1. First of all, is this approach good?
   There will be a lot of AJAX calls from clients,
   may be this could be a problem.
2. How to handle code complexity on client side?
   So far I have decided to use dojo.require / dojo.provide feature and divide the client side code into modules
   (for production they will be put together using dojo build system)
   I am thinking about to use kind of IoC container on client side, but not sure which one yet.
   It is very likely that I will write one for myself, it should not be difficult in dynamic language like JavaScript.
3. How to handle AJAX calls on server ?
   Should I use WCF on server side ? Or just ordinary ashx handler ?
4. How to handle code complexity on server side ?
   I want to use Spring.NET. May be this approach could help with modularity problem.
5. Data access - here I am pretty sure what to use:
   For DAL classes I will use nHibernate. Then I compose them with business classes using Spring.NET.

I would really appreciate some advice about which way to go.
I know about a lot of technologies, but I have used only little part of it.
I don't have time to explore all of them and be fine with the decision.

Comment: I dont think IoC for JS will be neccesary. I would also recommend ASP.NET MVC and mention that your website will not work without javascript.

Comment: "everybody work on something else". This doesn't sound like a good idea. I would advise you to start working at least in pairs on each subject to prevent anyone from becoming a bottleneck.

Comment: also take a look at WCF REST features... it simplifies a lot the access to web services (as it consists in building the correct url). Also MS provides the concept of "DataServices" (formerly called Astoria) which allow to create web services endpoints (rest compatible) for CRUD operations. At least, why using nHibernate and not stay in 100% MS techno (EF Code First is great :))

Comment: @Steven: even if I agree with you, this is not the question :)

Comment: @Steve B: That's the beauty of this comments section, I don't have to answer the question ;-)

Comment: @Steven: we are small company and not many of would like to learn something new. The result is two options: stay with them, do the work the old way OR do it your (new) way, but then you are alone :)

Comment: @Seve B: Thanks for info. I will take a look on REST implem. for WFC. I have learned and used nHibernate for few small projects and I find it quite good. Why not 100% MS techno ? Because I don't like evrything, for example MEF. Comparing to Spring.NET - I like Spring much more. It allows you to put together totaly idependent parts which don't know nothing about each other and moreover they don't know nothing about Spring.NET (of course, there are cases when the "parts" must know little bit).

Comment: I believe NHibernate is the best ORM out there, but after doing some research on EF Code First approach, I can appreciate it's value, but there are some scenarios where NHibernate seems to take advantage that may or may not apply to you: NHibernate seems to handle legacy database scenarios better; Nhibernate + Fluent NHibernate is actually quite good to manage; Nhibernate works better with different DB, but to be honest is not that common you will be switching DB. I think NH is just more mature.

Comment: WCF is great in the sense that provides highly configurable services for different purposes.

Comment: Thank you. I will now spend sometime getting into EF. Then I get back here and drop some comment. Btw.. why nobody write answer as answer ? :) ... this is my first day here, may be I am missing something :)

Comment: @Ernesto: While I have no experience myself with NHibernate, following questions about O/RMs here at SO regularly, it seems that LINQ support of NHibernate still lacks far behind. I think this is a pity.

Comment: I would use MVC to build a REST service. imho you get a much better structure than you can with WCF.

Comment: @Steven: I've had no problems with LINQ in nhibernate. Which features are you missing?

Comment: @Jgauffin: I'm not missing anything. As I said, I have no experience with NHibernate myself. When reading threads here at SO however, it seems like NHibernate can not do more than simple LINQ statements and fails at queries that are more complex in nature. However, those statements might be biased and the quality of LINQ over NHibernate might improve on a weekly base.

Comment: @Jgauffin and @Steven, NHibernate dialect does have some issues when it comes to dealing with complex predicates and queries in LINQ, but not a show stopper, most times you can just rewrite or simplify the query a bit. And also there is HQL which is also pretty powerfull. And you can even use named queries. Regarding LINQ since EF is Microsoft, probably integrates really well with LINQ, so that could be an advantage if you rely heavily on LINQ queries.

Comment: As for why do we comment and not answer, I believe an answer is SO is a very elaborate response, with even some research involved, that can help a lot of people, while a comment is my way of maybe helping you or someone else getting to the complete answer. It's just my way of seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

We do this type of single page interface where I work on a pretty large scale for our clients. (Our site is not an internet site)

1. This seems to work pretty well for us.  The more js you have the more difficult it gets to maintain, so have as many automated js tests as you can and try to break up your js logic in an mvc fashion.  4.0 is supposed to make this much easier.
2. Ext 4.0 has this built in if you are trying to limit the code you bring down.  If you have the same users day after day, then I think it would be best to just bring all the source down (compressed and minified) and cache it.
3. We've found asmx to work really well.  I have nothing against wcf, but last I looked it seemed like more trouble than it was worth.  I know they have made many improvements recently. asmx just works though (with a few request header changes and managing the "d." on the client side).
4. Our Server side data access layer is pretty complex, but the interface for the ajax calls is pretty simple.  You have not really given enough info to answer this part.  I would start as simple as possible and refactor often.
5. We are also using nHibernate.  Works fine for us.  We have built a DDD model around it.  It can take a lot of work to get that right though (not sure if we have it right after months of working at it).

If I were you I'd start with just extjs, your web service technology, and nHibernte.

Comment: Thanks everybody for answers.
@Jerry: did you mean "Domain Driven Design" by DDD ?

Comment: Yes DDD is Domain Driven Design.  It works well for us, but it could be overkill depending on what you are doing.  Our old system used to implement the same validation logic all over the place (and they never matched), so DDD helped us centralize.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor instead of a lot Javascript and calls to Service you can just do ajax calls to an Action in a Controller and that will let you have more maintainable code and use a IoC like Ninject. EF instead of NHibernate.
But it's your decision.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using a tool like [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/), especially if you're dealing with a very large project.  I don't have too much experience with ExtJS, but large projects in JavaScript are *hard* and something like Closure Compiler tends to make it easier.